# Print immediately on same line on the console screen

Tags: windows, fortran, intel-fortran

I'm trying to print some indicator of the progress of long iterations on the console screen. Specifically, I want something like this to be displayed on the console screen:

```
----|----|----|----|
```

This is, print `-` after each iteration (not multiple of 5), and print `|` after each 5 iterations. This is supposed to happen in real time: one character per iteration.

I tried using the `WRITE` statement with the `ADVANCE='NO'` option, but the desired output is only displayed on the screen after all the program is executed, or after I use another `WRITE` statement with an `ADVANCE='YES'` option.

This is my code:

```
PROGRAM TEST

  IMPLICIT NONE
  INTEGER :: i

  DO i = 1,20
     CALL SLEEP(2)
     IF (MOD(i,5).EQ.0) THEN
        WRITE(*,'(A)',ADVANCE='NO'), '|'
     ELSE
        WRITE(*,'(A)',ADVANCE='NO'), '-'
     END IF
  END DO

END PROGRAM TEST
```

I'm using the `SLEEP` subroutine to simulate the fact that each iteration takes a lot of time.

Comment: What compiler are you using? The program works as intended compiling with gfortran 5.4.0.

Comment: I'm using Intel Fortran on a Windows machine. So maybe this is a compiler-specific issue?

Comment: Looks like. You should check the Intel compiler version and see if the no advance instruction works ok. It could also be a problem of the terminal though.

Comment: Look for info about I/O buffering and when does the buffer get flushed. I would use other means to achieve your effect though. This is something than could differ between Linux and Windows.

Comment: I'm not married to this approach. It was the first one that came to my mind. Any suggestion about other ways of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following IanH and DannyVanpoucke's suggestion about the flush statement, this is a version of the code that works as intended:

```
PROGRAM TEST

  IMPLICIT NONE
  INTEGER :: i

  DO i = 1,20
     CALL SLEEP(2)
     IF (MOD(i,5).EQ.0) THEN
        WRITE(UNIT=6,FMT='(A)',ADVANCE='NO'), '|'
        FLUSH(UNIT=6)
     ELSE
        WRITE(UNIT=6,FMT='(A)',ADVANCE='NO'), '-'
        FLUSH(UNIT=6)
     END IF
  END DO

END PROGRAM TEST
```

As pointed in some of the comments below the question, it seems that the need to use the flush statement to make the information in the buffer available is an Intel Fortran specific issue.

Answer (score 3):

A flush statement can be used to signal that data that has been written to a file be "made available".  What that statement means is still processor dependent, but typically you will get the behaviour along the lines of what you want from your question.

The flush statement requires a unit number.  For output to the console you can use OUTPUT_UNIT from ISO_FORTRAN_ENV.  Intel Fortran 17.0 and earlier should then show the behaviour you want, for current ifort beta you also need to use OUTPUT_UNIT in the write statements (this is probably a compiler/compiler runtime bug).

(You should also fix the syntax error in your WRITE statements.)

Answer (score 1):

It is true that your setup should theoretically work (taking into account the different behavior of different compilers and such). The suggestion above of using the FLUSH(index) statement, using the index related to your standard output should even resolve the differences between different compilers. However, in some environments (more specifically clusters and HPC-supercomputers) this will still not solve your problem. While [implementing a progress-bar myself](https://dannyvanpoucke.be/fortran-dlls-en/) I ran into the same problem, bringing me to the following conclusion:

> HPC systems may perform extensive buffering of data before output, to increase the efficiency of the machine (disk-writes are the slowest memory access option)…and as a result this can sometimes overrule our flush command. The progress-bar in turn will not show much progress until it is actually finished, at which point the entire bar will be shown at once. There are options to force the infrastructure not to use this buffering (and the system administrators in general will not appreciate this), for example by setting the compiler flag **-assume nobuffered_stdout**. So the best solution for HPC applications will be the construction of a slightly modified progress bar, where the carriage return is not used.

You can easily test this by running the same code on your desktop, where the FLUSH statement will provide you the expected behavior.